# how to create ios testflight without MAC (visual studio 2019)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Is it possible to create an .ipa file in visual studio 2019 without MAC device.
I have tried this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows) but it doesn't generate the file since I am not connected to MAC.
My project is Xamarin Form IOS and Visual Studio 2019. I have apple developer account.

Comment: you can use AppCenter or Azure Build Pipelines to build iOS apps

Answer (score 0):

Without Mac it is impossible. You can also use Mac on cloud service.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).